# lasso or rectangle matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have created a scatter graph in matplotlib, however I would like to make it interactive. I would like it so I can select multiple plotted points on the graph.
I have seen the lasso function on the matplotlib site, but do not know how to put into my code, as some of the code is in the main bit.
What I would prefer is to have is much like the zoom function example, where you have a rectangle. However I have no clue of how to do this

My code so far just allows you to select one point

```
  def showFrame(self, msg):

   self.pubsubText.SetLabel("This is the Contact Map for the chain "+msg.data[0]+" in the PDB file "+msg.data[1])
   self.dpi = 100
   self.fig = figure.Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=self.dpi)
   self.canvas = wxagg.FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, -1, self.fig)
   self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

   self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
   self.vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
   self.vbox.AddSpacer(25)
self.toolbar = wxagg.NavigationToolbar2WxAgg(self.canvas)
self.vbox.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.EXPAND)
   self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
   self.vbox.Fit(self)


def draw_figure(self):

    def onpick3(event):
           ind = event.ind
           print('onpick3 scatter:', ind, np.take(x, ind), np.take(y, ind))
    self.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    self.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
       self.axes.clear()
       x, y= [e[0] for e in number_list],[e[1] for e in number_list]
       self.axes.scatter(x, y,color="black",picker=True)
    self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
       self.canvas.draw()
draw_figure(self)

frame=self.GetParent()
frame.Show()
```

Basically what I am asking is how can I apply either the lasso or the rectangle to my code

Comment: can you fix up the formatting in your code?